# Identify SF novel with spider-legged one-eyed robot

Tags: story-identification, robots

I read this novel sometime in the 1980s or so, I think.  It takes place on Earth where
an alien artifact is found.  It has a hatch that opens periodically, from which
a one-eyed multi-legged alien guard robot emerges.  The robot is curious, so they lure it away
and manage to open the hatch, and find that the interior is a vacuum with no gravity,
i.e., a kind of portal into space.  Someone goes in wearing a spacesuit, taking a clipboard on which he is to write about what he experiences using a pre-arranged code.  He has a cosmic revelation and not only refuses to come out, but tries to pull another man in with him to share the revelation.